# Android Studio .aar dependency causing errors

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am using Android Studio to create a sharable library in the .aar format.

The app/build.gradle file in my library project specifies the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.3'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'}
```

This works well and all of those dependencies can be used to build my library project.

I run into problems when trying to use this library project to build an app.

In the app's build.gradle file I specify my .aar as a dependency. I am able to create instances of classes that reside in my .aar file, however I run into issues when trying to create an instance of LocalBroadcastManager in my application.

The problem seems to stem from the fact that in my library project I need an instance of LocalBroadcastManager and so I include 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+' as a dependency. In the app I'm writing I also need to create an instance of LocalBroadcastManager. I can't seem to create an instance in my application without including the v4 support library as a dependency in my app as well.

If I don't include the v4 support library in my app's build.gradle I get the error:

**error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;**

If I include the v4 support library in my app's build.gradle I get the error:

**Error: duplicate files during packaging of APK /Users/myComputer/Development/OfflineAarTest/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-unaligned.apk
    Path in archive: res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
    Origin 1: /Users/myComputer/Development/OfflineAarTest/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_
    Origin 2: /Users/myComputer/Development/OfflineAarTest/app/libs/app-offline-debug.aar**

It seems that although my library project doesn't include any resources that I created, something that I am using as a dependency must be including a resource directory and files that are colliding with resources in the application.

I feel like I'm not understanding something about how dependencies work. Can anyone help me out?